# Incorrect number of SE sites on SO about page

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

https://stackoverflow.com/about reports that "Stack Exchange is a network of 116 Q&A sites just like it." However, https://stackexchange.com/ reports that there are "115 Q&A sites." (Which agrees with https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) And then we have https://data.stackexchange.com/ showing 227 different sites. (Note, however, I did not manually count here. I ran `$(".site-list:first > li").length`.)

All in all, **how many sites are there?**

Answer (score 3):

115 - SO - MSO = 113

(main + meta) * 113 = 226

226 + SO + MSO - (the one you're on) = 227

So there are 113 "normal" sites plus the special SO and MSO, for a total of 115 in data.SE.

One more started but not yet in the data dump makes it 116.